# How to activate Clip Editor only in Motion Tracking workspace

Tags: python, scripting, tracking, movie-clip-editor, workspaces

I am attempting to use script to add a sequence of frames directly into the clip editor of the Motion Tracking workspace. I need them in this workspace so I can then track motion without having to manually change the panels. What I have so far

```
for ws in data.workspaces:
            if ws.name == "Motion Tracking":
                bpy.context.window.workspace = ws
                bpy.context.area.type = 'CLIP_EDITOR'
```

changes the Text Editor area in the Scripting workspace to a clip editor and adds the images there. It also changes the context to Motion Tracking but the clip editor in that workspace remains empty. I am still learning about Blender and its API (although I am experienced in general Python) so it was also my understanding that in order to motion track through scripting, I still must activate that workspace. Please let me know if there are any errors in this reasoning and of any suggestions you may have. Thank you!